# Running out of memory with gwt:run-codeserver

Tags: gwt, maven, maven-3

I have a large GWT application that I'd like to test through Super Dev Mode.

When running the app with

```
mvn gwt:run-codeserver
```

it will compile OK and provide the URL for the server. At this point I fire up my app in a web browser and try to compile it again use the bookmarklets. This second compile brings up a range of memory errors like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space    
...
[ERROR] Out of memory; to increase the amount of memory, use the -Xmx flag at startup (java -Xmx128M ...)
```

So it's no secret that I need to assign more memory to the Java process running the server. What I can't work out is how to do that.

I have the following in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>                                    
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt.maven.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx2048M -Xms1024M -Xss1024k -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:PermSize=128M</extraJvmArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My MAVEN_OPTS environment variable is set to

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048M
```

And I have tried executing maven with

```
mvn -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs=-Xmx2048M gwt:run-codeserver
```

I have also tried it with the Oracle JDK and the open source JDK supplied with Fedora.

Nothing makes any difference. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I can confirm that this is an issue with the Maven plugin, and not the code. Running the project using IntelliJ's built in support for Super Dev Mode allow me to compile and recompile the application just fine. So this boils down to knowing the correct way to increase the memory that the Maven plugin has access too. It is obviously not one of the ways I have tried above...

Comment: Is it a big application. i.e More than 25 screens or atleast 10k lines of code?

Comment: It uses Errai and binds to a number of JAX-RS interfaces, so it ends up being a big application.

Comment: To rule out coding issue reduce the application size ( drop number of screens ). Start from 5 and keep on increasing your application screen count. If it breaks at particular "number" of screens. Then its time to "modularize" your application dev environment.

Comment: <extraJvmArgs> is the way!!! Can you monitor your RAM/CPU consumption in task manager with eclipse or jprofile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this was my fault. The POM.XML had some settings for the gwt plugin used when compiling against a profile, which had the memory settings configured correctly, and then another set of  gwt plugin settings not tied to a profile (which I had not noticed).

So when I was compiling for a specific profile (the app server), everything was fine. The settings defined in the profile were being applied, and everything worked as you would expect. But when I running in superdevmode without any profiles set, the second, less specific settings were being used over and above anything I was setting on the command line.

I ended up debugging the problem using the `-X` maven flag, which dumps out the configuration actually used by the gwt plugin. If anyone has the same problem, look for the output like the sample below. From this you can tell what setting was finally applied, which you can then use to find out where it is set.

```
[DEBUG] --- exit fork of org.jboss.pressgang.ccms:pressgang-ccms-ui:1.0-SNAPSHOT for org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1-rc1:run-codeserver (default-cli) ---
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1-rc1:run-codeserver (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <bindAddress>${gwt.bindAddress}</bindAddress>
  <codeServerPort>${gwt.codeServerPort}</codeServerPort>
  <extraJvmArgs default-value="-Xmx1024m">-Xmx1024m</extraJvmArgs>
  <gen default-value="${project.build.directory}/.generated">${gwt.gen}</gen>
  <genParam default-value="true">${gwt.genParam}</genParam>
  <generateDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/gwt"/>
  <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath default-value="false">${gwt.gwtSdkFirstInClasspath}</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>
  <inplace default-value="false">${gwt.inplace}</inplace>
  <jvm>${gwt.jvm}</jvm>
  <localRepository>${localRepository}</localRepository>
  <logLevel default-value="INFO">INFO</logLevel>
  <module>${gwt.module}</module>
  <persistentunitcache>${gwt.persistentunitcache}</persistentunitcache>
  <persistentunitcachedir>${gwt.persistentunitcachedir}</persistentunitcachedir>
  <pluginArtifacts>${plugin.artifacts}</pluginArtifacts>
  <project>${project}</project>
  <remoteRepositories>${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}</remoteRepositories>
  <style default-value="OBF">${gwt.style}</style>
  <version>${plugin.version}</version>
  <warSourceDirectory default-value="${basedir}/src/main/webapp"/>
  <webappDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}">${gwt.war}</webappDirectory>
</configuration>
```